# Online or offline text to html entities converter

Tags: php, html, markup, html-encode

Does anyone know of any online or offline software that will take, say, a paragraph of text with quotes and other characters in it and convert it to html entities ?

I am not looking for the normal alphabetic characters to be converted, just the quotes and dashes etc.

Reason I ask is that we have a copywriting department who insist on using Word for writing copy for websites but copying and pasting this into a site whilst having to find the strange characters is time consuming and tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP functions `htmlspecialchars` makes this easy. You can easily make a small html form who posts to a php script that write out the result.

PHP:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['input']);
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
<textarea name="input"></textarea>
</form>
```

http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: Totally forgot about that. Good idea. :D